# How to change .Net Core 2.1 project to .Net Core 2.0 project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, vs-web-application-project

Having trouble converting my .Net Core 2.1 project to .Net Core 2.0. I changed the target build type in my project solution properties as well as target framework in my .csproj file. Visual Studio will not let me build this application because the project is still inherently .Net Core 2.1.

Comment: Any particular reason you want to downgrade?

Comment: [Upgrade you must.](https://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2018/06/27/net-core-21-upgrade-you-must)

Comment: Using the project on software that can only work with 2.0 and before

Comment: Can you post your `csproj` file?

Comment: Don't forget core 2.0 specific support ends in October 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar issue recently. Cleared my packages folder and vs cache. Restarted vs, and everthing did build fine.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the target framework in my .csproj file and what did the trick for me was reinstalling older NuGet packages.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue
Deleting the content of the "bin" folder did the trick